# Why my C# code runs on Windows but throws Exception in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, exception, .net-core

I am working in .netcore3.1 in visual studio 2019 and I have written a method called ping() in my code. When I run the application in Debug mode, it works perfectly fine. Also, when I publish it for Windows and execute it, it works fine. But when I publish it for linux and run on a linux machine, it throws a NullReferenceException on a 'for loop'.
Exception Message is: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at  in \PingIo.cs:line 13 (line number 13 of the code below i.e., `for (int i = 0; i < PING_PACKET_SIZE; i++)`)

I don't understand why it gives a null reference exception on a for loop which is using a constant variable? and if there is a mistake, why it crashes only in linux and not on windows?

Please help.

```
        public static double ping(string ipAddress, Int64 timeoutMs)
        {
            const Int32 PING_PACKET_SIZE = 64;
            const Int32 DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS = 200;
            try
            {
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
                options.DontFragment = true;

                var pingPkt = new List<byte>();

                for (int i = 0; i < PING_PACKET_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    var val = Convert.ToByte(i + '0');
                    pingPkt.Add(val);
                }

                int timeout = (Int32)(timeoutMs == 0 ? DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS : timeoutMs);

                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(ipAddress, timeout, pingPkt.ToArray(), options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    return reply.RoundtripTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Ping Reply was not received! Reply Status: {reply.Status}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any issues on the code, and nothing strikes out to me as "could possible go wrong with null-ref". Have you tried running it on another Linux box, just to make sure it's not something with the .net installation on the broken Linux box?

Comment: The published code that ran on Linux, has it been compiled in Release or Debug mode? Sometimes, linenumbers can be off. I'd probably add some logging and try again. Or (if possible) try to remote-debug "in-vitro", but logging can't hurt anyway.

Comment: Assuming the line specification is correct, the first consideration would be whether Int32 is generated correctly on the target system or is perhaps null.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @cwap I ran multiple .net published projects on the machine and they work fine

Comment: @Fildor I published it in Release Mode and have already added logging

Comment: @Maia I have used Int32 like 1000s of times in the same project but the exception is only occurring in this function

Comment: @jestro here it is:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Connector.PingIo.ping(string ipAddress, long timeoutMs) in D:\Projects\Connector\PingIo.cs:line 130

(I just posted the code of function in which the exception is occurring and line 130 in the trace is exactly line 13 of my posted code)

Comment: Yes, you print out the exception message. But that's obviously rubbish. There is _nothing_ in that line that _can_ be null.

Comment: @Fildor exactly! I myself am not able to figure out why it is giving null reference exception on a line where nothing can be null.
edit: I have logged 'ipAddress' and 'timeoutMS' that are the parameters of the function and their values are correct and not null